# Jenkins doesn't use the same credentials that the logged in user has

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, cmd, credentials

I'm running Jenkins on a Windows Server and want to have access to a mapped network drive. I run the Jenkins using the same user credentials that I'm logged in with. Here's the problem: I don't have the same access to the files on the mapped drive from Jenkins and my local command prompt. Here's what I get when I one to change the directory in Window Server `CMD`:

```
C:\Users\DevBuildUser>cd /d r:
R:\>
```

and this is what happens in Jenkins' `Execute Windows batch command` running on the same machine:

```
cd /d r: 
The system cannot find the drive specified.
```

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins will run that batch file as the SYSTEM user. Go to the TARGET machine, and add the name of the machine from which you're running the Jenkins instance, with full write permissions.

...and use the full path, e.g., \10.1.2.3\myshare\mynewfiles\

Alternatively:

```
whoami
net use R: \\server\share\dir
R:
mkdir zipme
```

Comment: this is weird, but I get the same user when I do `whoami` from local cmd and jenkins (the user which is logged in). I tried to add that user to the new drive but nothing changed

Comment: Ah, okay. That'll probably make things easier. This worked for me (switches to R;\ and creates a new directory). See edited answer.